# CSS Hover Changing All Of Class

Tags: css

I know this is a pretty newb question, but I cannot seem to find an answer to it via Googling. I am using the Chrome plugin StyleBot to alter the CSS of an internal tool used by the company I work for. So I only have access to editing CSS.

I am attempting to make it so when I hover a specific element on the page, it changes the background color to highlight the information. What I need to do is make it so that ONLY the .row element I am hovering changes. Currently the way I am doing this is changing ALL .row elements. Basically, with some back-end code they are generating a list, each item in the list is coded with this:

```
  <span class="row">
    <div class="boxy txtleft"><span title="Agent"></span></div>
    <div class="boxy"><span title="Status"></span></div>
    <div class="boxy txtright"><span title="Last Call"></span></div>    
  </span>
```

So in the live environment it looks some what like this and keeps repeating:

```
  <span class="row">
    <div class="boxy txtleft"><span title="Agent"></span></div>
    <div class="boxy"><span title="Status"></span></div>
    <div class="boxy txtright"><span title="Last Call"></span></div>    
  </span>      
  <span class="row">
    <div class="boxy txtleft"><span title="Agent"></span></div>
    <div class="boxy"><span title="Status"></span></div>
    <div class="boxy txtright"><span title="Last Call"></span></div>    
  </span>
  <span class="row">
    <div class="boxy txtleft"><span title="Agent"></span></div>
    <div class="boxy"><span title="Status"></span></div>
    <div class="boxy txtright"><span title="Last Call"></span></div>    
  </span>
```

The CSS I am using to try and highlight a row when I hover it:

```
.row:hover  {
    background-color: red;
}
```

I know why this would alter all the .row elements, but I cannot figure out how to make it alter ONLY the one my mouse is over. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It works how you want here: http://jsfiddle.net/tyLayh3c/ | Are you sure there isn't any other code that highlights it all?

Comment: As in. When you hover over the one element. It acts as if you've hovered over everything?

Comment: The code you are showing should work fine. This should not be the case. There would be some other css or script conflicting with the hover behavior.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/nu/ - You aren't allowed div elements there, that is probably teh cause of your problem.

Comment: OK, I dug a little deeper. It looks like nearly every element as a "row" class... Thanks for the help guys but I am not sure I will be able to work around this.

Comment: then post the entire code and we will

Comment: You guys actually gave me a great start here. Now that I know the code I worked used, I can go through and adjust every other element that has .row in it. IE, .row.min60.column and then force them to do nothing on hover, that way the hover only affects the one type of element... pain in the ass but whatevs.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you mean each single(descendant) element in row:

```
.row> *:hover   {
    background-color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/maio/tyLayh3c/1/

Answer (score 1):

Your current code does not highlight all the elements when one is hovered, it works like you think. Although, with the code you gave none of them will highlight since there is no size to the '.row' span's, they don't have any width or height for a background. So the following code worked for me:

```
.row span:hover  {
    background-color: red;
}
```

This selects the spans inside of the row and changes their bg colors.

http://jsfiddle.net/snoapps/2oha40h5/

**EDIT:**

maioman's response probably would be safer since you might add more elements to the .row that aren't span's, then their backgrounds wouldn't be highlighted. So `.row> *:hover {}` would work better then.

Answer (score -1):

Answering my own question here. Thanks you guys for validating that code will indeed work. It is in fact a problem with the rest of the web page so I now need to go through and manually tell it to not apply a hover to nearly every other element. Thanks again everyone!

Comment: Please delete your question or provide an answer that's useful to the community, then accept it.